# File i/o into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, io

This my first function ever written in Python so I'm sure there's a lot that's not correct. I'm trying to read in a filename of authors and their book's title in a format of Author,Title on each line into a dictionary of format:

```
{0: [" The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy", 'Douglas Adams' ] }
```

With the key incrementing as each line down is read. Here is my best attempt that I haven't been able to get running. Do you have suggestions? I'm just returning the 0th value to check that the function is working.

```
def read_books(file_name):
    data={}
    try:
        with open(file_name, "r") as fh:
            for line in fh:
                try:
                    (auth, title) = line.split('','')
                    for i in lines:
                        data[i]=[title.strip(), auth.strip()]
                except:
                    continue

        return data[0]

    except:
        return -1

print(read_books(books.txt))
```

Comment: Your code is badly indented (at least on SO) so in the current state, helping you will be very hard.

Comment: Could you please explain how it could be better?

Comment: You shouldn't use bare `except` clauses like that because they trap **all** exceptions, even those you probably need to see, like `SyntaxError`. Be specific instead—or at least leave it out while debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually on the right track. You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to also get current index/line number while iterating over the file.

Here is the updated version of your loop:

```
def read_books(file_name):
    data = {}
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
            try:
                auth, title = line.split(",")
                data[line_number] = [title.strip(), auth.strip()]
            except ValueError:
                continue
    return data
```

Comment: bare `try/except` sucks. Specially here where it has no reason to be catched.

Comment: Actually it is not, especially in this case because it is possible `.split()` might throw a `ValueError` in case of a wrong delimited line or there might be empty lines in the file.

Comment: Oh, true. In that case, I prefer testing the number of items before unpacking. Or be more specific about the exception.

Comment: @Scotchnowplease btw instead of returning `-1` in case of a nonexistent file, you can return `None` which is more common in Python unlike C.

Comment: @Scotchnowplease I skipped the outer `try/except` as I find it more meaningful to raise an error in case of a nonexistent file. But as I said above, you can return `None` instead of `-1` if you like. If file is found and read, it'll return `data`.

Comment: Worked a charm. Thanks so much for the help and extra knowledge Ozgur.